# Functional way to fill an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to fill an Array that describes a Matrix [[Double]]. Each element of the matrix is of the following form :

```
a(i,j) = exp(a*(i+j) + b*min(i,j))
```

Is there an elegant way of doing that rather than using 2 embedded loops ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` twice to create your `matrix`.  This is a functional approach that is really just two loops under the hood:

```
let maxi = 5  // largest acceptable index
let maxj = 3  // largest acceptable index

let a = 2.3
let b = 3.4

let matrix = (0...maxi).map { i in (0...maxj).map { j in exp(a * Double(i + j) + b * Double(min(i, j))) } }
```

which might be a little easier to read if we format it like this:

```
let matrix = (0...maxi).map { i in
                 (0...maxj).map { j in
                     exp(a * Double(i + j) + b * Double(min(i, j)))
                 }
             }
```

One advantage this has over using loops is that you can create a matrix that is read-only (`let`).  Of course, you can always make it `var` if you want it to be mutable.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with the min function. Error message :" Expression was too complex to be solve in  reasonable time;  consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub expressions"

I tried to replace the min by (i<=j ? i :j) but the message remains the same

Comment: Are you sure you typed it right? I tested on a playground before posting.

Comment: Are your a and b vars Doubles?

Comment: to be true the exact code I used is the following         let C = (1...n).map {i in
                    (1...n).map {j in
                        exp(Double(i + j) * m  + 0.5 * sigma2 * (Double(i + j) + 2 * Double(min(i,j)))   )
            }
        }

Comment: m and sigma2 are let doubles

Comment: Ok, that is a pretty complex statement. Do it in several steps, separated by semicolons if on one line. Last line should return the result.

Comment: how do you do that ?

Comment: Something like this: `let part1 = Double(i + j) * m; let part2 = 0.5 * sigma * (Double(i + j) + 2 * Double(min(i, j))); return exp(part1 + part2)`